# Creating a new PHP project with WAMP 2.5

Tags: php, web, localhost, wamp

I have a directory containing a basic PHP website like so:

- website/index.php
- website/pages/...
- websites/styles/...

I want to use WAMP to run this locally for development purposes. I thought this would be easy, but if I put my website folder in WAMP's "www" directory and click on it in WAMP's "My Projects" section, Firefox gives me a "Server not found" error.

After doing some reading I discovered that apparently a better way to do this these days is using Virtual Hosts, but I was unable to find any clear, official instructions on how to set this up, and the guide I found were either outdated or hugely complicated. Nonetheless I gave it a shot, but I didn't have a clue what I was doing, didn't manage to get it working, and reverted all my changes.

Can anyone offer me a solution, or direct me to some clear instructions? (Thanks.)

Comment: How to setup Virtual Hosts on a WAMPServer http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,124482

Comment: Thanks for the link (and for writing the guide, by the look of it!). However, I'm still having some difficulties. Firstly, when I browse to "localhost/website", it loads my homepage but without the stylesheet or any images (both are stored in subfolders in the project root folder). And secondly, I can't get the "My Virtual Hosts" section to appear in the wampmanager menu; I have added the parameter from the guide and restarted wampserver but I don't see it.

Comment: Post another question, here or on WampServer forum, and show your Virtual Host definition file along with relevant file structure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248683/stylesheet-not-being-displayed-in-wamp-project

Answer (score 1):

I also face this problem and that is solved by doing following steps...
1> open your **www** folder which is inside wamp folder.
2> open **index.php** file from that folder
3> At line no 30 change **$suppress_localhost = true;** to **$suppress_localhost = false;** 
4> Refresh page of localhost and now open project.
DONE.